# Circle with CSS

Tags: html, css

HTML:

```
        <ul class="list_header">
            <li><a href="#">06 december 2013</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">item2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">item3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">item4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">item5</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">item6</a></li>
        </ul>
```

CSS:

```
.list_header{
    font: italic 70% Georgia;
    margin: 15px 0 0 15px;
}
.list_header li{
    display: inline-block;
}
.list_header a{
    color: #bbb;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.list_header li:first-child :after{
    content: '/t';
    height: 3px;
    border-radius:  50%;
    background: #bbb;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 5px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 5px;
}
```

http://codepen.io/hristofor/pen/aILlC

How to made this circle smaller?
I tried to make the circle smaller with width and height but it didn't work.
What to do?

Comment: As an alternative: Use the circle character `•`. This usually fits to your font and inherits any font styling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First remove the tab character from the content, then specify `display: inline-block`, remove the padding, and set `width` and `height` to the same desired value.

Live example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Iyeth

The problem in your code is that the pseudo element is *inline*, so the width and the height depend from its content and other properties like `font-size`.

Comment: When i delete text from content, it ignore border-radius.And why do i have to remove display?